# How to use a Stack's Pop method in another method

Tags: c#, methods, data-structures, stack

I am attempting to write a program for an assignment that Pops and adds the first 2 items in a Stack. The program has a `Pop` method, but I would like to know how to call the method within the `Add` method. This `Add` is supposed to Pop the top two items in a stack, get their sum, and Push that sum to the stack. In my code below I call the `Pop` method twice inside the `Add` method, but when I display the stack, the stack still has all of the original values. Is there something more/else I need to go to get the `Pop` method to work?

```
class StackEmptyException : ApplicationException
{
    public StackEmptyException(String message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

class MathStack
{
    private int[] dataStack;
    private int size;        
    private int top = -1;

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return top == -1;
    }
    public bool IsFull()
    {
        return top == size - 1;
    }
    public void Push(int i)
    {
        dataStack[++top] = i;
    }
    public int Pop()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new StackEmptyException
                       ("Stack empty -- cannot pop");
        else
            return dataStack[top--];
    }
    public int Top()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new StackEmptyException
                        ("Stack empty -- top undefined");
        else
            return dataStack[top];
    }

    public MathStack()
    {
        dataStack = new int[10];
    }

    public MathStack(int s)
    {
        size = 10;
        dataStack = new int[size];
    }

    public void LoadStack(int v)
    {
        dataStack[++top] = v;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        int[] display = new int[dataStack.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataStack.Length; i++)
        {
            display[i] = dataStack[i];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", display[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        int add1 = dataStack[0];
        int add2 = dataStack[1];
        Pop();
        Pop();
        int sum = add1 + add2;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sum);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MathStack stack1 = new MathStack();
        stack1.Push(9);
        stack1.Push(8);
        stack1.Push(7);
        stack1.Push(6);
        stack1.Push(5);
        stack1.Push(4);
        stack1.Push(3);
        stack1.Push(2);
        stack1.Push(1);
        stack1.Push(0);

        stack1.Display();
        stack1.Add();
        stack1.Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinGosse is there a particular syntax for that `dataStack.top` doesn't seem to be valid?

Comment: Your `Add` method sums the first two items that were pushed into the stack, instead of the last two ones. Is that on purpose ? In your example, are you expecting to sum 9+8 or 1+0?

Comment: Is your assignment to _write_ a `Stack` class?  Note that C#, like most other languages, already has one.  Why is `Add` acting like a queue?  You're grabbing the first elements in the stack, not the ones at the top, the popped elements aren't the ones you're adding.

Comment: Also, your `Pop` method isn't the problem, it's the `Display` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

First, the `Display` method displays the whole array. Except that since you're not physically removing the items from the array, you need to stop at the index `top`:

```
public void Display()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataStack[i]);
    }
}
```

The second issue is your `Add`. From what I understand, you want to pop the last two items, sum them, and push the result. In your implementation, you are actually summing the first two items (not the last two). A better version would be:

```
public void Add()
{
    int add1 = Pop();
    int add2 = Pop();
    int sum = add1 + add2;
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", sum);
    Push(sum);
}
```

Notice how I do not directly access `dataStack`. If your API is correctly implemented, it should not be needed.